# Dynamic chart library

Tags: php, charts, yii

I need to dynamically build chart based on user's submissions. These submissions are done through long-polling. What I mean is that users submit values to the server, and then I need a graph that will be instantly built based on values. What library would you suggest to use in this situation? I am looking at http://www.jstat.org/demonstration and http://www.highcharts.com/ now, but would love to hear your advice.
My application is in php (yii framework)

Comment: Why not just build the chart client side, since you plan to be using JS charting libraries? No need for polling and server transactions then.

Comment: @Twisted Pear. Thanks for the comment. The chart is going to be built based on many users submissions, not just one user.

Comment: What about the Google vizualisation API?

Comment: @user194076 - Touche. Note the rate limits, size limits, and datapoint limits (IE can only handle a 2083 char url) of the GC API. I have used it in several sites, but it does have its limitations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you ever looked at [`flot`](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) or [`RGraph`](http://www.rgraph.net/)? I have found `Highcharts` to have a steeper learning curve than `flot` or `RGraph` (IMHO). You might get rolling faster with one of these two.